# Android TabHost inside TabHost's tab

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tabhost

greetings my fellow developers.
i am working on an android project in which i am using TabHost and inside 2nd tab i want to use another TabHost,
so far i have accomplished this
my main TabHost XML is

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/homeTabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--first tab content-->
                <include layout="@layout/content_blood_glucose_diary_home" />

                <!--second tab content-->
                <include layout="@layout/content_blood_glucose_diary_summary" />

                <!--3rd tab content-->
                <include layout="@layout/content_blood_glucose_diary_activities" />

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and my java code for this is

```
private void loadTabs(int tabhost, String tab1, String tab2, String tab3){
    TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(tabhost);
    host.setup();

    loadTab(host, R.id.homeTab1, tab1); //tab 1

    loadTab(host, R.id.homeTab2, tab2); //tab 2

    loadTab(host, R.id.homeTab3, tab3); //tab 3
}

private void loadTab(TabHost host, int tabid, String tab){
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec(tab);
    spec.setContent(tabid);
    spec.setIndicator(tab);
    host.addTab(spec);
}
```

which i am calling from my onCreate

```
loadTabs(R.id.homeTabHost, "Today", "Summary", "Activity");
```

up at this point things work greate
but when add another tabhost in my summary xml (like this)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/summaryTabHost"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--first tab content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/summaryTab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="tab1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--second tab content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/summaryTab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="tab2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--3rd tab content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/summaryTab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="tab3" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--4th tab content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/summaryTab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="tab4" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in my java file i add

```
private void loadTabs(int tabhost, String tab1, String tab2, String tab3, String tab4){
    TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(tabhost);
    host.setup();

    loadTab(host, R.id.summaryTab1, tab1); //tab 1

    loadTab(host, R.id.summaryTab2, tab2); //tab 2

    loadTab(host, R.id.summaryTab3, tab3); //tab 3

    loadTab(host, R.id.summaryTab4, tab4); //tab 4
}
```

this in my oncreate function which is

```
loadTabs(R.id.summaryTabHost, "All", "Yearly", "Monthly", "Weekly");
```

this should work...
because its same as first tab host one.. first tabhost tabs dont show yup..

but when i comment 2nd tabhost inside summary xml.. things look normal.

my diagnosis so far is that probably something is not sitting right with 2nd TabHost.

any ideas what might be wrong here??? any help is acknowledged!!

Comment: in this example... i created tabhost at bottom of screen, but if i make it at top of screen both tabhosts work just fine.. it also work fine if i create first tabhost top of screen and inner tabhost bottom of screen it also works..
it seems first tabhost only disapears when i try to do as i did in question

Answer (score 0):

TabHost is Depriected you can use tablayout
if you want to make tabs inside tab you can easily use it in internal fragment

[Androidhive tablayout tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)